# How to specify lodash.groupBy's return type with Typescript's Enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, lodash

How to specify lodash.groupBy's return type with Typescript's Enum?

```
enum Gender {
  Male = 'male',
  Female = 'female'
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

const people: Person[] = [
  { name: 'Mary', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Jerry', gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Joe', gender: 'male' }
]

type PeopleGroupedByGender = {
  [key in keyof typeof Gender]: Person[]
}

// HERE: I can't get it to work so that the return type is PeopleGroupedByGender, typescript compiler complains:
// Type 'Dictionary<Person[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'PeopleGroupedByGender': Male, Female ts(2739)


const groupPeopleByGender = (people: Person[]): PeopleGroupedByGender => {
  return _.groupBy(people, (person: Person) => {
    return person.gender === Gender.Male ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female
  })
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeAoKUCyBDANsFALxQDkEBwZANJlAGLCWEnkBmzVZ6AvuugCWIAC7J2uAMZEACsgDOAexBp6IXBGAAuKPJFJhAcwDc9QwmQ69BkCb4DJyvVAAOwRS8I65SJSADaALps-vSoUOqaOmR4SACetFDmIIhI0Zws1FC8dFjhkdrkAFLI8YnJqdGZZNm5aBEahWRFitQ0SRZp5NXZ6IECInFuUHIehDBIimBu8ABCcXApyGwYWP4A1sBxUMJQm3GK7FCDboewnYHeCspB9ugA9PdQABIAogBKrzoAklCSuCAyCIOsDBMCRIooAB3RRIda6SEiAAWuHBSKISGAIjASBUJyIgnkI3cnmAEymM3mi1S7Xx8kkBhcwMcEBcgkIKBZnlwwnkWgeTwAKkMiGQACKCSQiQTKXDxAA8Pj8QQAfDVCVAIIT5EZjuioOxFPh8IoobqXJM3EhpcAiexJtB8eRRqTydNgHMFp0yDo8IR2kxMsd5AAKABMAHYAMwATgAlAJ0I4QM5DJNpi7CFTOmwQ6dSVdfDdAnGrmMyenKV6lihiCrVFhMdjcVAAPoAOjTFPmeZJ-qgvaLIELfjjJHrqywUCbOJUVr8nZzxGX5xr7b9RAA-KvUuuqFAdNTkO3A1R6LwE7wgA

Answer (score 3):

**You** know that result of `groupBy()` is going to be an object keyed by the strings in Gender, but the type definitions for *Lodash* specify that it is returning a *Dictionary<T>* which is an object keyed by strings with type `T` values.

You have three choices:  Don't specify the return type of `groupPeopleByGender()`, and live with the string keys, casting the result of `groupBy()` to *PeopleGroupedByGender* since you know that's what the result will be, or override the type definitions of *Lodash*.

### Casting Solution

```
const groupPeopleByGender = (people: Person[]) => 
  <PeopleGroupedByGender>_.groupBy(people, (person: Person) => 
    person.gender === Gender.Male ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female);
```

### Modifing Type Definition Solution

I based the following on what's already in `collection.d.ts` and `common.d.ts`.  It uses TypeScript's declaration merging functionality to update the *lodash* module with a new implementation of `groupBy()` with a properly typed result.

Disclaimer: I don't understand the philosophy behind the design of their type repository, so I might have missed a nuance.  Use this as a guide to your final solution.

```
// lodash-extended.ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { List, ValueIterateeCustom, LoDashStatic } from 'lodash';

declare module 'lodash' {
  type StringishDictionary<V, K extends string> = {
    [index in K]: V;
  }
  interface LoDashStatic  {
    groupBy<T, K extends string>(
        collection: List<T> | null | undefined,
        iteratee?: ValueIterateeCustom<T, K>
    ): StringishDictionary<T[], K>;
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

enum Gender { Male = 'male', Female = 'female' }
interface Person { name: string; gender: string; }
const people: Person[] = [ /** Persons added here. **/ ]

const groupPeopleByGender = (people: Person[]) => 
   _.groupBy(people, x => (x.gender == Gender.Male) ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female);

// Groups will be keyed by Gender with values of Person[].
const groups = groupPeopleByGender(people);
// Below is valid syntax and will display the first Male.
console.log(groups[Gender.Male][0]);
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kv3egk?file=index.ts)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a casting as much as possible, so the problem is Lodash? like looking at this if there's a way I can redefine a groupBy return type of Dictionary<T, allowedKeys>, This would then work?

Comment: So your idea was a good one.  After looking up Declaration Merging last night, I modified my solution in order to add an overload to `groupBy()`.  No riggishness necessary.

Comment: Can you add the actual usage in the modified solution?